# Magento2 getting following error at time of deployment

Tags: magento2

Magento2.3.3 I am getting following error at the time of deployment

> The contents from the
>   "/mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/pub/static/frontend/hosemart/fittings/en_US/css/email.css"
>   file can't be read. 
>   Warning!file_get_contents(/mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/pub/static/frontend/hosemart/fittings/en_US/css/email.css):
>   failed to open      stream: No such file or directory

I have included email.less & email-inline.less in my custom theme.

Comment: Try run all command and apply permission...

Comment: I did but no success

Answer (score 1):

I just removed  `{{css file="css/email.css"}}` from header & it worked fine. Also, remove email.less from my theme.  JUst posting answer might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all cache, pub static folder and run static-content deploy again.

Comment: Not working already tried